# Google Maps overlay image not visible

Tags: android, maps, overlay

I want to overlay a map image (.jpg) over the Google Maps mapview.
The problem is: The overlay image is not showing, who knows what's the
problem?

There is no error in logcat and the MapView is working.

The code:

```
package nl.ultimo.android.skikaart;

import java.util.List;
import com.google.android.maps.GeoPoint;
import com.google.android.maps.MapActivity;
import com.google.android.maps.MapController;
import com.google.android.maps.MapView;
import com.google.android.maps.Overlay;

import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.graphics.BitmapFactory;
import android.graphics.Canvas;
import android.graphics.Point;
import android.graphics.Rect;
import android.os.Bundle;

public class MapsActivity extends MapActivity
{
        Bitmap          bmp;    //Loaded bitmap in memory
    GeoPoint        min;    //Top left corner (lat/long)
    GeoPoint        max;    //Right bottom corner (lat/long)

   /** Called when the activity is first created. */
   @Override
   public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
   {
       super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
       setContentView(R.layout.main);

       float lat1 = 45.19775f;
       float lng1 = 6.28418333f;
       float lat2 = 45.2636667f;
       float lng2 = 6.17431667f;

       min = new GeoPoint((int)(lat1 * 1E6), (int)(lng1 * 1E6));               // bounding rectangle
       max = new GeoPoint((int)(lat2 * 1E6), (int)(lng2 * 1E6));

       MapView mapView = (MapView) findViewById(R.id.mapView);
       MapController ctrl = mapView.getController();

       int x = (min.getLongitudeE6() + max.getLongitudeE6())/ 2;  //Select map center
       int y = (min.getLatitudeE6() + max.getLatitudeE6())/ 2;

       ctrl.setCenter(new GeoPoint(y,x));
       ctrl.setZoom(12);                 //Set scale
       mapView.setBuiltInZoomControls(true); //Enable zoom controls

       //Add overlay
       MapOverlay mapOverlay = new MapOverlay();
       List<Overlay> listOfOverlays = mapView.getOverlays();
       listOfOverlays.clear();
       listOfOverlays.add(mapOverlay);

       mapView.invalidate();
   }

   class MapOverlay extends com.google.android.maps.Overlay
   {
       @Override
       public boolean draw(Canvas canvas, MapView mapView, boolean shadow, long when)
       {
           super.draw(canvas, mapView, shadow);

           //Translate the GeoPoint to screen pixels
           Point screenPts = new Point();
           mapView.getProjection().toPixels(min, screenPts);

           //The overlay image
           Bitmap bmp = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(),R.drawable.skikaart);

           //Prepare two rectangles (pixels)
           Point top_left = new Point();
           mapView.getProjection().toPixels(min, top_left);
           Point bottom_right = new Point();
           mapView.getProjection().toPixels(max, bottom_right);

           Rect src = new Rect( 0,0,bmp.getWidth() - 1, bmp.getHeight() - 1 );
           Rect dst = new Rect( top_left.x, bottom_right.y,bottom_right.x,top_left.y );

           canvas.drawBitmap(bmp, src, dst, null);

           return true;
       }
   }


   @Override
   protected boolean isRouteDisplayed() {
       return false;
   }
}
```

Comment: where have you stored your image

Comment: Bitmap bmp = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(),**R.drawable.skikaart**);

Comment: You haven't marked anyone as the answer. Any reason why ?

Answer (score 8):

to see marker you need to do next

```
Drawable drawable = ...set your marker drawable
    drawable.setBounds(-drawable.getIntrinsicWidth() / 2, -drawable.getIntrinsicHeight(), drawable.getIntrinsicWidth() / 2, 0);
    overlayitem.setMarker(drawable);
```

Answer (score 3):

Just to make things clear here is a quote from reference

> "The setBounds(Rect) method *must* be called to tell the Drawable where it is drawn and how large it should be."

Answer (score 2):

Your code has one minor mistake.

Change

```
Rect dst = new Rect( top_left.x, bottom_right.y,bottom_right.x,top_left.y );
```

to

```
 Rect dst = new Rect( top_left.x, top_left.y,bottom_right.x,bottom_right.y );
```

and you should be good.

Answer (score 1):

Change this code

```
min = new GeoPoint((int)(lat1 * 1E6), (int)(lng2 * 1E6));  // bounding rectangle
max = new GeoPoint((int)(lat2 * 1E6), (int)(lng1 * 1E6));
```

instead of

```
min = new GeoPoint((int)(lat1 * 1E6), (int)(lng1 * 1E6));  // bounding rectangle
max = new GeoPoint((int)(lat2 * 1E6), (int)(lng2 * 1E6));
```

and try its working.

Comment: Set min and max as per requirement, your min and max are wrong so image is not display in map.

Answer (score 1):

Remember that draw() is called each time the overlay needs to be rendered.  When the map is being moved by the user, this could happen multiple times per second!!

You need to load the resource only ONCE, then only draw the bitmap onto the canvas during the draw invocation.

Also, your current implementation is highly coupled with the actual Activity.

in your activity

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);

    ...

    map.getOverlays().add(new PNGMapOverlay(getResources(), R.drawable.bitmap_id));

}


// allows re-factoring into separate class/file
class MapOverlay extends com.google.android.maps.Overlay
{
    private Bitmap bitmap;

    public MapOverlay(Resources resources, int resourceId) {

            bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(resources, resourceId);

    }

    @Override
    public void draw(Canvas canvas, MapView mapView, boolean shadow) {

    ...
            canvas.drawBitmap(bmp, src, dst, null);

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to add overlays into your `listOfOverlays`. Then only it will be shown on the map. For that you have to create an `overlayitem` using ur `geopoint` and then add it to the list of overlays.

For eg:

```
GeoPoint point = new GeoPoint((int) (latitude * 1E6), (int) (longitude * 1E6));
OverlayItem overlayItem = new OverlayItem(point, "", "");   
listOfOverlays.addOverlay(overlayItem);
mapView.invalidate();
```

Try and see. If you face any issue, please add as comments.

Comment: Thanks for you answer.
But i did add the overlay:

//Add overlay
        MapOverlay mapOverlay = new MapOverlay();
        List<Overlay> listOfOverlays = mapView.getOverlays();
        //listOfOverlays.clear();
        listOfOverlays.add(mapOverlay);        

        mapView.invalidate();`


I have specified two GeoPoints, 1 for the left upper corner of the overlay and one for the right bottom.

Answer (score 0):

I just spent ages pulling my hair out with the same problem as you. Turned out removing **android:layout_weight="1"** from my MapView declaration resolved the problem. Don't ask me why!